# DateTime.parse string was not recognised

Tags: c#, date, parsing, datetime

I can't understand why my string value keeps throwing an exception for what should be a valid string. I have a string date in the format `"30/09/2016 14:55:00"` (called `myDate`) and have tried the following to get it into a datetime format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime.Parse(myDate);
```

I can't see where I've gone wrong, is there something I've missed?

EDIT:

Current value of myDate

[image]

Keeps context when parse is called
[image]

The exception
[image]

The same is also true for all other versions of parsing a string to DateTime

Comment: I have also been looking at previous answers for this, for which all have pointed to the above with no success

Comment: So what exception do you get and what does it say? Everything works for me...

Comment: When I execute the second one it works. Are you 100% that the `myDate` is as you say?

Comment: @GiladGreen I'll post a screenshot

Comment: What *is* your current culture?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your answers, I didn't realise viewing a string in the visualiser wasn't an exact copy for copy on what you'd get, all great answers! It's a shame I can only choose 1!

Comment: @Novastorm - just as a side note, option 1 and 2 are identical. read last line of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your string has extra `"` and then when you parse it throws an exception. Your string of `"30/09/2016 14:55:00"` is actually `\""30/09/2016 14:55:00\""`

Remove the `\"` and then parse:

```
string myDate = "\"30/09/2016 14:55:00\"";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate.Replace("\"",""), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or because it is always at the ends of the string you can use the `.Trim` method

Answer (score 2):

You string contains additional quotes which you should remove before calling `DateTime.Parse`. You can remove the quotes by calling

```
myDate = myDate.Trim('"');
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Comment: Using `null` as a `IFormatProvider` _might_ be dangerous since it means "use `CurrentCulture` settings", OP's `CurrentCulture` might not use `/` as a `DateSeparator` and/or `:` as a `TimeSeparator`and in such a case, your code throws `FormatException`. It would be better to specify a _proper_ (maybe `InvariantCulture`) culture setting to prevent this kind of situations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have extra unwanted double quotes in your string.

Try this and see if it works:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate.Trim('\"'), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```